# Luigi DictParameter KeyError

Tags: python, keyerror, luigi

I have the following task

```py
class Test(luigi.Task):
    foo = luigi.DictParameter(default = {})
    ...
```

I am using a config file to run this

```
[Test]
foo = "{'a': 0, 'b': 1}"
```

I have also tried

- `'{'a': 0, 'b': 1}'`
- `"{"a": 0, "b": 1}"`
- `"{'a': "0", 'b': "1"}"`
- `"{'a': 0, 'b': 1}"`

They all fail with

```
KeyError: '"a"'
```

or

```
KeyError: ''a''
```

or some a related key error. What am I supposed to configure dictionaries as parameters when I am using a config file?

I tried [this was as well](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/pull/2540/files#diff-cad9e5db62cc0ddef86ccd865e31d465afe3b932208076805e66a8b169f63eb2R10) but even this does not work. This link is from the PR that fixes the loading of dictionaries from TOML files.

In the official docs of the `DictParameter` they suggest

> luigi --module my_tasks MyTask --tags

or

> luigi --module my_tasks MyTask --tags '{"role": "web", "env": "staging"}'

But there is no mention for a TOML file. [Even in their complex example TOML they do not include dictionaries](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/examples/config.toml)

I have to say that Luigi is one of the most ill-documented projects I've ever worked with unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while developing one of our projects. Unfortunately, we didn't find a solution that included dictionaries in luigi.cfg, instead we used a .yaml file and luigi.WrapperTask.

We did the following:

```
class BaseTask(luigi.WrapperTask):
  with open('/path/to/your/config.yaml') as f:
        foo_dict = yaml.safe_load(f)
  def requires(self):
    yield Test(foo=foo_dict)

class Test(luigi.Task):
 foo = luigi.DictParameter(default = {})
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me.

In your config file, do:

```
blah = "{'a':'b'}"
```

In your main file, you'd do

```
dict_param = luigi.DictParameter()

def run(self):
    parsed_dict_param = dict(eval(self.dict_param))
```

So the magic comes from eval.